# Mapping of protobuf's RepeatedField<T> type

Tags: c#, automapper, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Given these source classes (used in an EFCore application)

```
class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

and the following `Protobuf` message

```
message StudentDto {
    repeated int32 courseIds = 1;
}
```

How am I able to map `Student.Courses` to `StudentDto.CourseIds` using `AutoMapper`?
So far I tried the following:

```
class StudentProfile : Profile
{
    class Converter : IValueConverter<ICollection<StudentCourse>, RepeatedField<int>>
    {
        public RepeatedField<int> Convert(ICollection<StudentCourse> sourceMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return new RepeatedField<int> { sourceMember.Select(x => x.CourseId) };
        }
    }

    public StudentProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Student, StudentDto>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.CourseIds, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Courses.Select(x => x.CourseId)));
            //.ConvertUsing(student => new StudentDto{CourseIds = { student.Courses.Select(x => x.CourseId)}});
            //.ForMember(dst => dst.CourseIds, o => o.ConvertUsing(new Converter(), src => src.Courses));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var student = new Student
        {
            Courses = new List<StudentCourse>
            {
                new StudentCourse { CourseId = 1, StudentId  = 1 },
                new StudentCourse { CourseId = 6, StudentId  = 1 },
                new StudentCourse { CourseId = 11, StudentId = 1 }
            }
        };

        IMapper mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new StudentProfile())));

        var mapped = mapper.Map<StudentDto>(student);
        // Expecting: {{ "courseIds": [ 1, 6, 11 ] }}
        // Actually: {{ }}
    }
}
```

The `ConvertUsing` statement in `StudentProfile` works and maps the member correctly but as the classes I'm using in my project are far more complex, this is really the last option I would like to use.

Does anyone of you know the cause and a possible fix for this problem?
I'm using `Google.Protobuf 3.7.0` and `AutoMapper 8.0.0`.

**Edit:**
I already checked the execution plan but couldn't find any errors in there.
For the sake of completeness here I'll attach it here:

```
(src, dest, ctxt) =>
{
    StudentDto typeMapDestination;
    return (src == null)
        ? null
        : {
            typeMapDestination = dest ?? new StudentDto();
            try
            {
                var resolvedValue =
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return ((src == null) || ((src.Courses == null) || false))
                            ? null
                            : src.Courses.Select(x => x.CourseId);
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentNullException)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                };

                var propertyValue = (resolvedValue == null)
                    ? {
                        var collectionDestination = (ICollection<int>)((dest == null) ? null : typeMapDestination.CourseIds);

                        if ((collectionDestination == null) || collectionDestination.IsReadOnly)
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            collectionDestination.Clear();
                        }

                        return new RepeatedField<int>();
                    }
                    : {
                        var passedDestination = (dest == null) ? null : typeMapDestination.CourseIds;
                        var collectionDestination = ((passedDestination == null) || ((ICollection<int>)passedDestination).IsReadOnly)
                            ? new RepeatedField<int>()
                            : passedDestination;
                        collectionDestination.Clear();

                        var enumerator = resolvedValue.GetEnumerator();
                        while (true)
                        {
                            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                            {
                                var item = enumerator.Current;
                                collectionDestination.Add(item);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        return collectionDestination;
                    };

                return propertyValue;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new AutoMapperMappingException(
                    "Error mapping types.",
                    ex,
                    AutoMapper.TypePair,
                    TypeMap,
                    PropertyMap);

                return null;
            }

            return typeMapDestination;
        };
};
```

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu already checked that one but couldn't find any errors. I attached it to the question

Comment: If you replace RepeatedField with a List it should work. If that's the case, look into RepeatedField and find out how it's different from a List and how you would map that by hand. Then reduce that to smth AM supports.

Comment: I don't think I can replace RepeatedField that easy as the code gets generated by Protobuf.

Comment: That's not exactly relevant, is it? :) You still have to understand how that can be mapped. And the more you isolate the issue, the easier it will be.

Comment: yes of course i have to understand that but it has to work in the context i have and thus i have to work with RepeatedField but maybe i dont get what you mean?